# Graphite: multiple series with a single command

Tags: graphite

I would like to put two series in the same graph on the graphite *dashboard*. However, since the dashboard requires single-line commands I could not find a way that doesn't involve the use of a wildcard.

Here's an example of the two series I would like in the same graph:

```
sum(base.foo.bar.positive.*)
sum(base.foo.bar.negative.*)
```

I tried several separators but I could not get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a few options here...

- Merge the 2 graphs on to the graph via the drag and drop in the *dashboard*

**OR**

- Use the [sumSeriesWithWildcards](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.sumSeriesWithWildcards)() function

**Merge 2 or more wildcard matching**

2. Open your first graph on the dashboard
3. Open your second graph on the same dashboard
4. Click and hold the second graph and drag it over the first graph

**Use groupByNode() and wildcard matching**

This is not as nice, and will not always work however you will be able to do this all in one line.

```
sumSeriesWithWildcards(base.foo.bar.{positive,negative}.*, 3)
```

This will do the following:

- Select all all the graphs that match base.foo.bar.positive.* and base.foo.bar.negative.*
- Sum the data by the node at position 3: positive, negative

You might want to have a read over the following page: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html

Comment: Braces to the rescue!