# Grafana dividing 2 series

Tags: graphite, grafana, divide

I'm trying to divide 2 series to get their ratio.
For example I'm got sites (a.com, b.com, c.com) as * (All sites)
Each of them has total sections count and errors occurred stats. I'm wanna to show as bars errors/sections where section > errors for each site to each erros for this site. Here I'm whant to got 3 bars.

So:

A parser.*.sections.total

B parser.*.errors.total

X-Axis Mode:Series
Display:DrawMode: Bars

When i'm trying to use divideSeries I'm always got **VallueError**(divideSeries second argument must reference exactly 1 series)

Answer (score 2):

A new function [divideSeriesLists](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.divideSeriesLists) was introduced in [Graphite 1.0.2](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1_0_2.html) for dividing one series with another. Both the series should be of same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapSeries with divideSeries to do vector matching of series in Graphite (or maybe asPercent depending on which version of graphite you are using).

An example query:

```
aliasByNode(reduceSeries(mapSeries(groupByNodes(parser.*.{sections,errors}.total, 'maxSeries', 1, 2), 0), 'asPercent', 1, 'sections', 'errors'), 0)
```

I'm not sure what aggregation function you are using so substitute `maxSeries` for the function you need.

Check out this [blog post](https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2017/01/29/graphite-and-grafana-how-to-calculate-percentage-of-totalpercent-distribution/) about using mapSeries with divideSeries for more explanation.

Here is an example from our system in the Grafana query editor:

[image]