# grafana - divide series with wildcards

Tags: grafana, graphite

I'm trying to build a list of percentages in grafana, but am having trouble getting `divideSeries`+wildcards to work right.

I found [Grafana dividing 2 series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714008/grafana-dividing-2-series) which seemed like what I wanted, but unfortunately there's no `mapSeries` function in my grafana instance (version 4.6.0-1).

This is what I've got, but instead of specifying the ID "1234", I want to use a wildcard, and have each ID grouped together.

```
divideSeries(stats.dhcp.pools.1234.cur,stats.dhcp.pools.1234.max)
```

Logically, I tried: `divideSeries(stats.dhcp.pools.*.cur,stats.dhcp.pools.*.max)` -- but that does not work. I tried mucking around with `asPercent`, but it has the same limits as `divideSeries` does.

I think `applyByNode` is what I want, but I can't seem to translate the example into something that actually works.

Comment: Just a note: Which functions Grafana shows for Graphite depend on your Graphite version. You can change the version in the data source settings if you have a recent version of Graphite installed.

Comment: Odd, I'm using the latest graphite-api version (graphite-api-1.1.3-3.el7). From my understanding, graphite-api implements all the graphite-web functions, but I guess I've got a starting point to dig into.

Comment: Required installing from the github url: `pip install git+git://github.com/brutasse/graphite-api.git`

Comment: In Grafana, there is a version field in the data source settings - you should change that to 1.1.x to see all the new functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use graphite as datasource (I think). Functions you mentioned are implemented in [graphite-web](http://graphite.readthedocs.io), you can find docs also for [`applyByNode`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.applyByNode)

```
applyByNode(
    stats.dhcp.pools.*.*,
    3,
    'divideSeries(%.cur, %.max)',
    '% pct'
)
```

Note that as of November 2017, applyByNode is not in the default graphite-api install, and requires installation from the github source:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/brutasse/graphite-api.git
```

As a side note - you can use any of graphite function, even `mapSeries`.